# How do you find the phase shift in a sin equation when fitting a trigonometric model to data?

Tags: algebra-precalculus

I am going through Ron Larson Calculus book and at page 33, there is an exercice called Fitting a Trigonometric Model to Data.

We have to create a sin function that graph the number of minutes of daylight at a certain location during the year. We are given:

June 21 = 801 minutes

December 22 = 655 minutes.

We are asked to use $t_0=$ december 22.

The book offer the amplitude as (801-655)/2, or 73 and the author offer one possible model:
$$ d=728-73sin(\frac{2\pi t}{365}+\frac{\pi}{2}) $$
[image: Graph of this function]

I can see how this model works perfectly but I don't understand how $\frac{\pi}{2}$ end up there using the formula bx-c=0

using $$a sin(bx-c)+d$$

a= $$|a|\to |-73| \to 73$$

b = $$period=\frac{2\pi}{b} \to 365=\frac{2\pi}{b} \to b = \frac{2\pi}{365}$$

x-scale = $$\frac{p}{4} \to \frac{365}{4} \to 91.25$$

d = $$728$$

c = ???

I can reverse engineer c from the equation, $$bx-c=0 \to\frac{2\pi t}{365}+\frac{\pi}{2}=0 \to \frac{2\pi t}{365}= -\frac{\pi}{2} \to4\pi t=-365\pi \to t=-91.25$$

Which equal to $-\pi/2$ but how can you come up with $\pi/2$ in the first place?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The model seems to come from the idea that $t=0$ on December 22,
when the length of the day is $655.$

Using $t$ as the independent variable instead of $x$,
your general formula for a sinusoidal curve becomes
$a\sin(bt − c) + d$.
With $a = -73,$ $b = \frac{2\pi}{365},$ and $d = 728$,
the length of the day on day $t$ is

$$ -73\sin\left(\frac{2\pi}{365}t − c\right) + 728 .$$

But knowing that the length is $655$ when $t = 0$
(on December 22), we can write an equation,

$$ -73\sin\left(\frac{2\pi}{365} \times 0 − c\right) + 728 = 655 .$$

Notice $0$ plugged in as the value of $t$.

Simplify the multiplication by zero:
$$ -73\sin\left( − c\right) + 728 = 655 .$$
Subtract $728$ from each side:
$$ -73\sin\left( − c\right) = -73.$$
Divide by $-73$ on each side:
$$ \sin( − c) = 1.$$

What value of $c$ can make this true?

Actually an infinite number of values of $c$ could be used, since you can take any such value, add $2\pi$ to it, and get the same value from the sine function.
But the first thing that comes to my mind is
$\sin(\pi/2) = 1,$ and therefore it makes sense to set

$$ -c = \frac\pi2. $$

And now we know the last unknown parameter of the model,

$$ -73\sin\left(\frac{2\pi}{365}t + \frac\pi2\right) + 728 .$$

Comment: Ok, I get it now. thank you so much! It finally all make sense!